What does hwp_dynamic_boost do in the intel_pstate frequency scaling driver?
Looking at the intel_pstate kernel documentation, apparently hwp_dynamic_boost should dynamically increase performance when a task waiting on IO is selected to run.
Enabling this feature will not allow me to change the energy performance preference while the governor is set to performance. If the governor is set to powersave I can change the EPP.
Which raises the question: What is HWP dynamic boost supposed to do? When enabled it either maxes out the EPP or doesn't do anything depending on the value of the governor.
Also I couldn't notice any dynamic p-state switching. Each CPU just locks at a set EPP and never changes no matter how much I keep monitoring each core even under load (maybe it happens inside the CPU and unrelated to the scaling driver?). All synthetic benchmarks with or without dynamic boost seem within margin of error with RAPL reporting the same power consumption. I know that according to the documentation it should change when an IO task resumes and not under 100% load but I just don't know how to test that. Testing how "smooth" the device feels is also not possible for me as my CPU is quite overkill and any small changes on non full loads are barely noticeable.
So I thought it would be easier just to ask whether someone already knows the functionality behind this feature, how does it impact power consumption and how to leverage it in order to optimize power to performance balance in my device.

Apparently the not being able to change EPP does not depend on hwp_dynamic_boost even with it off, the ability to change EPP will depend on the governor being set to powersave, which raises even more doubts on whether hwp_dynamic_boost is even doing anything.
